# Complex Math Formula: Predict the value of variable if result is known

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, data-structures, prediction

I have a very complex math formula/equation which involves exponential.

Formula: `X + 2 = Y`

*PS: The above is just an example to illustrate my problem. The real formula is way more complex than this.

There is no way for me to form an equation with X variable on the left like `X = Y - 2`. I tried professional Math software like `Maxima` and `Mathematica` to solve the equation but failed.

I was given the value of Y, how can I find/estimate the value of X?

My current idea is start looping X = 1 and increase X's value with a fixed increment in each loop and try to match my value Y. The only relationship I have now is that the greater value of X generates a smaller value of Y.

Is there any good algorithm out there for my problem?

Comment: This is an algebra problem: solve for X.  You need to refactor the equation to isolate Y, and then code that.  In this case, X = Y -2.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn I had solved this problem. Just to let you know that my formula is way complex than what you can think of. It involves x^2, x^6, x^-0.09, x^-0.21 and lots of sqrt. Anyway it's solved with root finding algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equation cannot be solved analytically, you need to use numerical algorithm. To make it simple rewrite the equation into form of X + 2 - Y = 0.

Then, it becomes a problem of [finding a root of equation using numerical method](https://www.google.cz/webhp#q=root+of+equation+numerical+method).

Comment: Numerical algorithm works perfectly in this case. Thanks!